# Mobx observerable

Tags: javascript, mobx

[Mobx document](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html)

> Using ES6 Map constructor you can initialize observable map using observable(new Map()) or for class properties using the decorator @observable map = new Map().

when i run following code

```
observable(new Map())
```

**throw error**

Uncaught Error: [mobx] The provided value could not be converted into an observable. If you want just create an observable reference to the object use 'observable.box(value)'

I don't understand。why?

help me!
thanks

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Maybe you have a problem with `import` statements or your *compilation* process?

```js
import { observable } from "mobx";

const a = observable(new Map());

a.set("t", 1);
console.log(a.get("t"));
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-map-test-bjd9q)

Comment: thanks!    Reason for this phenomenon is， i use babel `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`。